# Adding a JScrollPane to a JTable component

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I am trying to add a `JScrollPane` to my `JTable`, but it doesn't seem to works. I have a `JTable` with 21 rows and 5 columns, and I'm adding a `JScrollPane` as per the following code...

```
public Targy_felv() {
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(600, 300);
    table = new JTable();
    Object o[] = new Object[]{"Tárgynév", "Oktató", "Kredit", "Félév", "Tárgykód"};
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(get_Tárgyak(), o));
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(table);
    frame.add(table);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Could someone please help me to understand why the scrollbars aren't appearing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you're adding the `JScrollPane` to your `JFrame`, not the `JTable`. If you originally just had a `JFrame` and a `JTable` you would have added it like this...

```
JTable table = new JTable();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(table);
```

If you're adding the `JScrollPane`, you need to change your `add()` method to add the `JScrollPane` instead of the `JTable`, either like this...

```
JTable table = new JTable();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

or like this, if you need to reference the `JScrollPane` later in your code...

```
JTable table = new JTable();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: :-) Thanks, yeah it was, but looks like it paid off. Was just counting on the user not adding the JScrollPane properly to the JFrame/JPanel.

Comment: No problems :-) Please make sure you 'tick' to accept the answer, so everyone knows your question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the initial code frame.add(table); change 'table' to 'scrollPane' and it works.