# Adding JScrollPane to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I've been working on this for awhile but can't seem to get the scroll pane added. I'm creating a JFrame, adding a JTable to that frame and then updating cells in a for loop. But I can't get the JScrollPane to add without it crashing. I also couldn't declare the column headers without it crashing. Any ideas would really be appreciated.

```
 frame6.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images\\iconimage.jpg"));
 frame6.pack();
 frame6.setResizable(false);
 frame6.setVisible(true);
 frame6.setSize(400,200);
 frame6.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
 int w = frame6.getSize().width;
 int h =  frame6.getSize().height;
 int x = (dim.width-w)/2;
 int y = (dim.height-h)/2;
 frame6.setLocation(x, y);

 JPanel btnPnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
 JPanel topBtnPnl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
 JPanel bottombtnPnl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

 JButton close = new JButton("Close");
 bottombtnPnl.add(close);

 btnPnl.add(topBtnPnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
 btnPnl.add(bottombtnPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);


defaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(list.size(), 6);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
frame6.add(table, BorderLayout.NORTH);



JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane();
table.add(jps);


table.setValueAt("FIRST NAME", 0,0);
table.setValueAt("LAST NAME", 0, 1);
table.setValueAt("CLUB", 0, 2);
table.setValueAt("POSITION", 0, 3);
table.setValueAt("AGE", 0, 4);
table.setValueAt("COUNTRY", 0, 5);

int j = 0;

for(i = 0; i < PlayerManager.list.size(); i++){

     if(list.get(i).getPosition().toUpperCase().equals(pPosition.toUpperCase()))
    {
    table.setValueAt(PlayerManager.list.get(i).getfName(), j+1, 0);
        table.setValueAt(PlayerManager.list.get(i).getlName(), j+1, 1);
    table.setValueAt(PlayerManager.list.get(i).getClub(), j+1, 2);
    table.setValueAt(PlayerManager.list.get(i).getPosition(), j+1, 3);
    table.setValueAt(PlayerManager.list.get(i).getAge(), j+1, 4);
    table.setValueAt(PlayerManager.list.get(i).getNationality(), j+1, 5);
    j++;
        }
    }

frame6.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame6.add(btnPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

frame6.setTitle("Player Table");


close.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    frame6.setVisible(false);
    frame6.dispose();
}
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the table to the scroolpane and not vice versa

```
    JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane();
    jps.add(table);
```

instead of

```
    JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane();
    table.add(jps);
```

And also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619048/adding-a-jscrollpane-to-a-jtable-component). Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same problem, with the JScrollPane not displaying, thanks for the input though.

Comment: JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(table); // forgot about this one