# TableModel not called in a JScrollPane containing a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, abstracttablemodel

I am having an unexpected behavior with the Java GUI. I want to create a `JScrollPane` containing a `JTable` then add this `JScrollPane` to a `Frame`.

Here is the code :

```
public class UrlsScrollPanel extends JScrollPane {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public UrlsScrollPanel() {

    //setup urls and collections
    ArrayList<URL> urls = URL.getAll();
    ArrayList<Collection> collections = new ArrayList<>();
    for(URL url : urls) collections.add(new Collection(url));

    //table
    String[] columns = {            
        "database",
        "status",
        "consumption",
        "last snapshot date",
        "last message",
        "details",
        "stop collect"
    };  

    AbstractTableModel dataModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            System.out.printf("row: %d, column: %d \n", rowIndex, columnIndex); //is never called.
            URL url = urls.get(rowIndex);
            Collection collection = collections.get(rowIndex); 
            ArrayList<Message> lastMessages = collection.getLastSnapshot().getMessages();
            Message lastMessage = lastMessages.get(lastMessages.size() - 1);

            if(columnIndex == 0) return url.toString();
            if(columnIndex == 1) return collection.getStatus(); 
            if(columnIndex == 2) return ConsumptionChart.getChartPanel(collection);
            if(columnIndex == 3) return collection.getLastSnapshot().getDate();
            if(columnIndex == 4) return String.format("[ %s ] %s", lastMessage.getDate(), lastMessage.getBody()); 
            return "Comming soon.";
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return urls.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    JTable table = new JTable(dataModel);
    add(table);
    setBackground(Color.red);
    setSize(500, 500);
}
}
```

And here is how I call it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    UrlsScrollPanel panel = new UrlsScrollPanel();
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
}
```

The result is a red square blinking at the top left of the frame then disappearing immediately. Also the `dataModel` seems to be never called.

Any help in what I am doing wrong is much appreciated, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't *extend* `JScrollPane`. Instead, use your `table` to *construct* a `JScrollPane`:

```
frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The approach is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show); a complete example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38192710/230513); an alternative approach using `setViewportView()` is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32461092/230513).

> Are these two not similar?

```
JScrollPane panel = new JScrollPane(); panel.add(table);
…
JScrollPane panel = new JScrollPane(table);
```

No. As shown in [*How a Scroll Pane Works*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#operation), the first formulation adds the `table` directly to the [`JScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html), replacing the [`JViewport`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html) component that occupies the central position in the [`ScrollPaneLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ScrollPaneLayout.html) and that would have been used to display the `table`. The second formulation invokes `setViewportView(table)` internally, which tells the scroll pane's `JViewport` what component to display.

Comment: Ok, I just changed, my class is not extending JScrollPane anymore and posses a method getPanel(). However I still don't understand why my previous approach is not working.  
  
Is   
`JScrollPane panel = new JScrollPane();  
panel.add(table);`  
not similar to `JScrollPane panel = new JScrollPane(table)` ?  
  
Thanks for your help!  
  
PS: there is no need to specify BorderLayout.CENTER when adding a component to a JFrame because this is the default layout.

Comment: Good question; I've elaborated above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense now!